# CanJS Observable and dots in keys

Tags: javascript, observable, canjs

My problem is while using canJS Observable I can't use dots in object keys, because can think that some nesting available here.

So let's say if I create new observable:

```
var obs = new can.Observe( { "div.test-class": { "color": "#000000;" } } );
```

can fails with message

```
can.Observe: Object does not exist
```

And I can't create observable using just

```
var obs = new can.Observe( { ".test-class": { "color": "#000000;" } } );
```

because now can fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: current._set is not a function
```

Creating observable using following code

```
var obs = new can.Observe( { "div": {}, "div.test-class": { "color": "#000000;" } } );
```

works perfectly but I DON'T NEED nesting, and can tries to nest `test-class` into `div` inside observable.

So, any thoughts how I can achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a bug [and has been fixed in version 1.1.5](https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/257). The general rule now is:

```
var obs = new can.Observe( { "div": {}, "div.test-class": { "color": "#000000;" } } );
```

Will create the observe you expect. Passing an object to `.attr` like

```
obs.attr({ 'my.test': 'testing' });
```

Will also set `my.test` as the property. Passing it as a setter like

```
obs.attr('my.test', 'testing');
```

Will set `{ my: { test: 'testing' } }`.