# CanJS models: attr function and nested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, canjs, canjs-map

In [canJS](http://canjs.us/) I can set a model property with `person.attr('name', 'John Doe');`, but sometimes that property contains nested data, so I need to do the following:

```
var address = person.attr('address');
// Update country
address.country = 'USA'; 
person.attr('address', address);
```

Is there a shorter solution for this in canJS?

Comment: related question with dots:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529342/canjs-observable-and-dots-in-keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
person.attr('address.country', 'USA');
```

http://canjs.us/#why_canjs-flexibility (See the "Engineered limber" section)

PS: I see the `canjs` for the first time, googled the answer in seconds using "canjs nested objects" request

Comment: Thank you! Good point, I was reading the old documentation and I didn't find it there.